# Incompatible Qt libraries and the CUDA toolkit

Tags: qt, debugging, cuda

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 (actually pop os, same version)

I've got the CUDA toolkit installed from the ubuntu repositories, which installs version 11.5.

The OS and CUDA toolkits were the first things installed so I haven't played around with different versions, other Qt software, etc.

I can write CUDA code, compile it an run it just fine, the installation seems to work. However, if I try to run nsight-sys, or ncu-ui, I get the error message

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.15.3) with this library (5.15.2)
```

What is this due to. A few days ago it actually complained comparing 5.13.3 to 5.13.2, so it seems any Qt update that happened in between updated two wrong versions?

How do I make the CUDA debugging tools run with whatever Qt library I have installed in my system?

Comment: Which Qt version do you have installed? Which version does the Cuda debian package depend on? What does `ldd ncu-ui` show for Qt? (Edit the question with this info).

Comment: Anyway, try `apt-get source` for the CUDA packages you installed, and try compiling it yourself. Searching for how to build debian packages from sources should be easy, and building should be then easy too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a nsight-compute / nsight-systems package issue. As a workaround, you can follow these 4 steps to manually import the library causing the conflict (`libQt5Network.so`) from [this Debian package](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/libqt5network5_5.15.2+dfsg-9_amd64.deb.html):

1. Download libqt5network5 (from Qt 5.15.2) package from Debian repository

```
$ wget -q 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5network5_5.15.2+dfsg-9_amd64.deb'
```

2. Extract package

```
$ dpkg -x libqt5network5_5.15.2+dfsg-9_amd64.deb .
```

3. Copy missing library and its associated symlinks to Nsight Compute installation

```
$ sudo cp -P usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so* /usr/lib/nsight-compute/host/linux-desktop-glibc_2_11_3-x64/
```

4. Copy missing library and its associated symlinks to Nsight Systems installation

```
$ sudo cp -P usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so* /usr/lib/nsight-systems/host-linux-x64/
```

After following these steps, tools will start normally.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Gonna have to learn to track specific versions myself.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for reporting this! I tracked this using `strace` and examined all the calls to `open`/`openat`. It is a very powerful tool to understand what a program is doing, because syscalls (+ memio in some cases) are the only way for a program to do more than computations.

Comment: This did not work for me. I am on Ubuntu 22.04, and I have the same error message, even after following these instructions.

Comment: @DimitriLesnoff can you please confirm libQtNetwork.so.5 is present in the Nsight Compute directory? Use command `ls -alh /usr/lib/nsight-compute/host/linux-desktop-glibc_2_11_3-x64/libQtNetwork.so.5`.
If the binary is indeed present, can you please check which directories Nsight Compute is trying to look up `libQtNetwork.so.5` from? Use command `strace -f ncu-ui 2>&1 | grep libQt5Network.so`. Thanks!

Comment: I do not have `libQtNetwork.so.5` but I have:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 Jan 29 12:30 libQt5Network.so.5 -> libQt5Network.so.5.15.2

Comment: I get twice the following output for the `strace` command:
[pid 15736] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/nsight-compute/host/linux-desktop-glibc_2_11_3-x64/libQt5Network.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15736] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/lesnoff/flint/lib/libQt5Network.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 15736] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

Comment: Downloading the latest version (.run executable) of nsight compute from nvidia's website works like a charm for me. Ubuntu packages have not been updated since 2021.

Comment: Correct, NVIDIA packages work, the version that does not work is the one from the Ubuntu jammy package repository.